How do I run JavaScript in .NET 8 Blazor Web App?
My code was a bit more complex but I cut it down to the most simple use case to simplify the problem: "Show an alert box with a message"
I can make it work in .NET 7 Blazor Server but the exact same thing does not work in .NET Blazor Web App.
What did I try:
.NET 7 Blazor Server:
I create a new app with the Blazor server template.
I create a new nav item, same as the existing ones: Shared/NavMenu.razor.
<div class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="component">
        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Component
    </NavLink>
</div>

Then I add a Blazor Component: Pages/Component.razor
@page "/component"

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button @onclick=ButtonClicked>Perform interop</button>

@code
{
    private async Task ButtonClicked()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "Button event fired");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Hello world");
    }
}

The alert box is displayed when I click the button and is logged to the browser console.
Browser console in developer tools:
[2024-04-11T08:04:30.710Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://localhost:7004/_blazor'. blazor.server.js:1

[2024-04-11T08:04:30.736Z] Information: WebSocket connected to wss://localhost:7004/_blazor?id=_4uKQ. blazor.server.js:1

Button event fired blazor.server.js:1

.NET 8 Blazor Web App
I create a new app with Blazor Web App template:
Interactive render mode: Server
Interactivity location: Per page/component
I create a new nav item, same as the existing ones, in Components/Layout/NavMenu.razor (same as above).
I add a Blazor Component: Components/Pages/Component.razor
@page "/component"

@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<button @onclick="ButtonClicked">Perform interop</button>

@code
{
    private async Task ButtonClicked()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("console.log", "Button event fired");
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("alert", "Hello world");
    }
}

The button is there but nothing happens when I click on it. No 'alert' and the the browser console is empty and nothing is logged to the console.
Edit: added code from .NET 8 Blazor Web App

Post the code you actually tried. It may seem the same to you but have subtle differences (like the missing quotes). The code you posted looks identical to the Blazor 8 examples so whatever is wrong, it's not a change in Blazor 8

you could try  @rendermode InteractiveServer after @page

If your page has no render mode set then it's static and won't work

The only thing I can see wrong is you are missing double quotes around the javascript function call of ButtonClicked:
<button @onclick="ButtonClicked">Perform interop</button>


I just tried this: <button @onclick="ButtonClicked">Perform interop as you suggested.
It works both with and without "" in .NET 7 Blazor Server but none of them works in .NET 8 Blazor Web App

Post your actual code in the question. What you tried is the same as the Blazor 8 doc examples. Either there's something wrong in your code, or even the Blazor team doesn't know the way you call JS changed (unlikely).

Thank you. I updated my question with the code

The correct answer for this [duplicate] Question is found by clicking on the link at the top of this page.
